# PNG image modified after image uploads in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, image, upload

I have Uploaded .PNG image for the product. But it displaying differently on the frontend. most of the image automatically become transparent. please check the attached image. [image]

Comment: Can you please upload your png.

Comment: sure. https://i.imgur.com/GKnDRPM.png  please check

Comment: @Vinz please check the image

Answer (score 0):

I tried to upload your picture on luma theme and I have the same issue.

[image: luma issue]

When I tried to open the picture in a new tab, I saw that the blue background is tranparent so it had been removed.

[image: New tab]

So I saved it in Jpg and reupload it and it works !

[image: Working]

If you want the jpg : [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvZoQ.jpg)

Comment: Hi @Vinz | its png kind of product

Comment: Your picture is the problem. If you want to absolutely use a png you have to edit it.

Comment: The problem resolved. Changed the image adapter from default to ImageMagik. and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: not the problem with the image actually. some thing is happening while the image resized to distribute for different thumbnails.